# Applying CSS to entire page without <head> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I manage an enjin (CMS/Hosting) site for (wanted a drupal one for them, but they went with enjin) a PC clan and have been adding touches and features to it with javascript. We recently swapped domains and so instead of manually changing a whole bunch of links we used javascript. So, if somebody doesn't have it enabled, most links will be broken. So, i wanted to use something like this:

```
<noscript>
<style type="text/css">
.pagecontainer {display:none;}
</style>
<div class="noscriptmsg">
You don't have javascript enabled.  Good luck with that.
</div>
</noscript>
```

However, I don't have access to the  tag. The way enjin does things, I put code into a module which i can place anywhere and hide it there if I want, basically making that code useless, as it only makes a tiny square in the module and displays the text. I was wondering if there was a way to get the same effect without utilizing the  tag.

Comment: "You don't have javascript enabled.  Good luck with that." Cute.

Comment: Copied it off another stackoverflow question. I'm a nub at JS.

Comment: so you want the head tags visible, if javascript is disabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
<noscript>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 3000; 
            height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF">
    <p style="margin-left: 10px">You don't have javascript enabled.  Good luck with that.</p>
</div>
</noscript>
```

Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431137/how-to-wrap-noscript-tag-to-hide-content-when-javascript-disable) since it's basically the same thing.

Comment: Attempted this, however it didn't seem to parse the code within the <noscript> tags and just displayed the contained code as text in the spot I placed the module.

Comment: I take that back. I had to move the noscript above some JS in the same module.