# Show for JavaScript enabled clients only (i.e. anti-NOSCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

From a widest compatibility with various browsers perspective, what is the best way to show content for only JavaScript enabled clients?  There have been similar questions, however, they are old and in conflict.

- [How to wrap <noscript> tag to hide content when javascript disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431137/how-to-wrap-noscript-tag-to-hide-content-when-javascript-disable)
- [Is there a HTML opposite to <noscript>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319/is-there-a-html-opposite-to-noscript)

I have seen other options, however, it seems like these two are the best?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>anti-noscript</title>
        <noscript><style> .yes_script1 { display: none } </style></noscript>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(function(){
                $('.yes_script2').show();
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .yes_script2{display:none;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="yes_script1">Show to JavaScript clients only.</p>
        <noscript>Show to non-JavaScript clients only.</noscript>
        <p class="yes_script2">Show to JavaScript clients only.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Insert the content with Javascript, or hide it with CSS and show it with Javascript.

Comment: Load everything reliant on JS using XMLHttpRequest? It'll be slow and fragile (it's how the Twitter website used to work before they realised just how slow and fragile it was) but it'll only work if script is enabled and allowed.

Comment: @Peter.  Why don't you recommend the `noscript` in the head solution?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you linked a pretty good answer in your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/431554/2373138

```
<head>
    <noscript><style>.jsonly { display: none; }</style></noscript>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jsonly">javascript users only</div>
</body>
```

Another common solution is to use javascript itself for that:

```
<head>
    <style>
        .jsonly { display: none; }
        .js .jsonly { display: block; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        document.body.className = "js";
    </script>

    <div class="jsonly">javascript users only</div>
</body>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kelunik/ryxgt4dL/embedded/result/)

However, this solution will fail for inline elements, because it will override the `display` property, but here's a fix, just replace the CSS before with the following:

```
body:not(.js) .jsonly { display: none; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kelunik/ryxgt4dL/1/embedded/result/)